# A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList...and MIME media type text/xml was not found

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, jersey

Im using Jersey to build a REST Service and want to return a `Collection<String>` as XML.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
@Path("/directgroups")
public Response getDirectGroupsForUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId) {
    try {
        Collection<String> result = service.getDirectGroupsForUser(userId, null, true);

//      return result; //first try
//      return result.toArray(new String[0]); //second try
        return Response.ok().type(MediaType.TEXT_XML).entity(result).build(); //third try
    } catch (UserServiceException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

but my attempts fail with the following exception:

> javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type text/xml was not found

and all results to that exception I found via google dealt with returning text/json instead of text/xml like in my situation.

Can anyone help me? I thought, if I use a Response, that would be my root element in XML and my collection a list of string elements in it..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**NOTE:** Although this answer works, [anar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18240578/1818625) is better.

You should try to use a JAXB annotated class to solve your problem.  You could change your method to this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
@Path("/directgroups")
public Groups getDirectGroupsForUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId) {
    try {

        Groups groups = new Groups();
        groups.getGroup().addAll(service.getDirectGroupsForUser(userId, null, true));
        return groups;
    } catch (UserServiceException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And then create a JAXB annotated class for your groups.  I have included a generated class for you, using the process described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15552881/1818625).  Here is an example of the documents that it will produce:

```
<groups>
  <group>Group1</group>
  </group>Group2</group>
</groups>
```

And here is the generated class:

```
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element ref="{}group" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "group"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "groups")
public class Groups {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<String> group;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the group property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the group property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getGroup().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link String }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<String> getGroup() {
        if (group == null) {
            group = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.group;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there no other way? I thought Response would do the job for what you created the class Groups. -> provide a container for the list an act as root element

Comment: At a minimum, something needs to tell Jersey the name of the root XML element.  It looks like you could use a [generic wrapper and JAXB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1603484/1818625) or the [XStream library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8427694/1818625).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342218/getting-error-a-message-body-writer-for-java-class-java-util-arraylist-listjava ..can you solve this ??

Answer (score 49):

Use

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
GenericEntity<List<String>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<String>>(list) {};
Response response = Response.ok(entity).build();
```

The Generic entity wrapper works to get the output when using the Response builder.

[Reference](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html)

Comment: sadly the link you referenced here is now dead, but would have been really helpful

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html

Comment: and https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.5.1/jersey/index.html?javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html

Comment: Even though this worked for me, I prefered this solution which was even simpler ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136404/severe-messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-application-json-type-class#answer-29136934

Answer (score 0):

**The only thing that worked for me so far is to create my own Wrapper object.**

Don't forget the ***@XmlRootElement*** annotation to explain JAXB how to parse it.

Note that this will work for any type of object - in this example I used ArrayList of String.

e.g.

The Wrapper object should look like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class ArrayListWrapper {
    public ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

And the REST method should look like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
@Path("/directgroups")
public ArrayListWrapper getDirectGroupsForUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId) {
    try {
        ArrayListWrapper w = new ArrayListWrapper();
        w.myArray = service.getDirectGroupsForUser(userId, null, true);
        return w;
    } catch (UserServiceException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding @XmlRootElement(name = "class name") to the object I want to return , resolved my issue