# Does rest supports arraylist of objects?

Tags: java, rest, object, arraylist

I am having a class BookMain which is returning an arraylist of objects. I am using REST service to get the output, but I am getting an error.

*This is my BookMain class:*

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public ArrayList<Object> addObjects() {

    Book book = new Book(); 
    book.setName("The Book");
    book.setAuthor("Author");

    BookStore bookstore = new BookStore();
    bookstore.setName("The Bookstore");
    bookstore.setLocation("UK");

    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(book);
    list.add(bookstore);

    return list;   
}
```

*This is the error which I am getting:*

```
11 Jul, 2013 3:36:52 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>, and MIME media type application/xml was not found 11 Jul, 2013 3:36:52 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.
ContainerResponse write SEVERE: The registered message body writers 
compatible with the MIME media type are:application/xml ->
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App
```

Can anyone provide me a solution for it ?

Comment: the content-type of your output page seems to be `application/xml` so you should send back ArrayList serialized to xml ?

Comment: The below could help you , [A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList…and MIME media type text/xml was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41429076/8228918)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Introduce a new  class as below

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "responseList")
public class ResposeList {

    private List<Object> list;

    public List<Object> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

and set the list as below

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public ResposeList addObjects() {

    Book book = new Book(); 
    book.setName("Here is the Game");
    book.setAuthor("HHH");

    BookStore bookstore = new BookStore();
    bookstore.setName("Prateek Bookstore");
    bookstore.setLocation("Vasanth Nagar");

    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(book);
    list.add(bookstore);
    ResposeList books=new ResposeList();
    books.setList(list);

    return books;   
}
```

Comment: Hey man, I don't want to introduce a new class in my project. There are already 50-60 classes in it. If I introduce a new class to achieve this I need to introduce around 20 more classes. Is there a way to resolve this issue without introducing new classes ??

Comment: Hey I edited answer.Now you can use this class only for everywhere you return list

Comment: I figured it out, we need to include the sub-classes in the Response list class using XmlSeeAlso annotation

Comment: Thank you for your precious time :)

Comment: @Prats Ahh yes you need to define classesToBeBound property as a list  for Jaxb2Marshaller .Anyway glad it works :)

Comment: Hey man, one more sugession I require from you. If I am adding a list (i.e.list.add(<list>)) and then setting the ResposeList object, it is giving me error. Could you tell me why ?

Comment: it is not allowed to add a collection to a List<Object> ,you can only add a object there,I mean something extends object,List does not extend Object instead it implements Collection .You need List<List<Object>> for achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your entity(Arraylist) under the Response object. Also your rest method return type should be Response. Here is what you need to do:

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response addObjects() {

    Book book = new Book(); 
    book.setName("Here is the Game");
    book.setAuthor("HHH");

    BookStore bookstore = new BookStore();
    bookstore.setName("Prateek Bookstore");
    bookstore.setLocation("Vasanth Nagar");

    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(book);
    list.add(bookstore);

    return Response.status(200).entity(list).build();
}
```

Also add `@XmlElemen`t on top of getter in your ResponseList bean

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ResponseList {

private ArrayList<Object> list;

@XMLElement("booksList")
public ArrayList<Object> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(ArrayList<Object> list) {
    this.list = list;
}   
}
```

Comment: I am getting following error while doing this: The method status(int) is undefined for the type Response. Any idea ?

Comment: From which one package have o imported 'Response' class?

Comment: @pWoz import com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Response;

Comment: try this one: `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`

Comment: @pWoz This one is working, but still I am getting the same error which I have mentioned in the question, its not getting resolved

Comment: @Prats You need to add XMLElement annotation on the list. I have updated the answer, check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use JSONArray to display the result.
Create a JSONArray object and pass the list to the JSONArray() constructor.
Then return the JSONArray object in string format.
Change the return type of your method to String and the flollowing code would work.

> Blockquote

JSONArray a=new JSONArray(list);
return a.toString();