# How to get different types of JSON objects form a single call in JAX-RS Jersey Restful web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I want to get three different types of objects (Object list) from a single service call. It's OK to get different objects from different call. Is it OK do do it in a single call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of different objects you want to return is limited to 3, then you can create a result object, which has properties for each of the three different objects you want to return

```
public class Result {

    private ResultOne resultOne;
    private ResultTwo resultTwo;
    private ResultThree resultThree;

    public ResultOne getResultOne() {
        return resultOne;
    }

    public void setResultOne(ResultOne resultOne) {
        this.resultOne = resultOne;
    }

    public ResultTwo getResultTwo() {
        return resultTwo;
    }

    public void setResultTwo(ResultTwo resultTwo) {
        this.resultTwo = resultTwo;
    }

    public ResultThree getResultThree() {
        return resultThree;
    }

    public void setResultThree(ResultThree resultThree) {
        this.resultThree = resultThree;
    }
}
```

If you want to return a true list of objects, see [Does rest supports arraylist of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590647/does-rest-supports-arraylist-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by two ways:
 Way 1: Make the required POJO class
for three different type of objects, you want to
return and
return this POJO class as output of web service call.

Way 2: Create a HashMap object.Push the key and corresponding object into the HashMap and
return that HashMap object.
e.g.

```
HashMap < String, List < String >> multipleObjectReturn = new HashMap < String, List < String >> ();

List < String > listObject1 = new ArrayList < String > ();
listObject1.add("List 1 Value2");

multipleObjectReturn.put("List Object 1", listObject1);

List < String > listObject2 = new ArrayList < String > ();
listObject1.add("List 2 Value1");

multipleObjectReturn.put("List Object 2", listObject2);
```

Finally,

```
return multipleObjectReturn.
```

Above, code is used to
return different type of list objects.
If you want to
return any type of objects, then use Object type instead of `List < String >` in HashMap.

```
HashMap < String, Object > multipleObjectReturn = new HashMap < String, Object > ();

HashMap < String, String > mapObject1 = new HashMap < String, String > ();
mapObject1.put("Key1", "Value1");

multipleObjectReturn.put("ListObject1", listObject1);                                  
multipleObjectReturn.put("ListObject2", listObject2);                                  
multipleObjectReturn.put("MapObject1", mapObject1);

return multipleObjectReturn;
```