# JAX-RS Print List of Object[] as json/xml

Tags: java, jax-rs

im knew to jax-rs

Can you please help me to know how to print jax-rs for a

```
List<Object[]>
```

?

Please, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can see this ([Does rest supports arraylist of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590647/does-rest-supports-arraylist-of-objects))

for jax-rs you can use Jersey

first you should create :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "responseList")
public class ResponseList {

    private List<Object> list;
    public List<Object> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

after we can use String as an object (or any Other object)  :

```
  @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public ResponseList addObjects() {

        String string1 = "s1"; 
        String string2 = "s2";

        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(string1);
        list.add(string2);
        ResponseList strings=new ResponseList();
        strings.setList(list);

        return strings;   
    }
```

pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </dependency>
```

and the result is :

```
<responseList>
    <list xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">s1</list>
    <list xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">s2</list>
    </responseList>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'Jackson library'

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(...your list object...);
```