# How to return List<String> from Rest webservices

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jersey-2.0

I want to return a `List<String>` from a Rest web service (in Java) in both XML or JSON. But I am getting an error:

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List&lt;java.lang.String>>.
```

Can you tell me how to return `List<String>` from Rest web services (in Java)?

Comment: can you please show your rest method code?

Comment: The below link could help you figure it out [A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList…and MIME media type text/xml was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41429076/8228918)

Answer (score 0):

Did you annotate your method with @ResponseBody or your class with @RestController? Is jackson on your classpath?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
@GET
@Path("list")
@Produces("application/json")
public List<String> getList() 
{
    return Arrays.asList("a", "b");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JAX-RS specification 2.0 you find in chapter 3.5 Declaring Media Type Capabilities

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/widgets+xml")
public class WidgetsProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<Widgets>
```

Implementing or having an implementation of the interface like this

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/json")
public class JsonProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<Object>
```

will probably do the trick.  I didn't test this though.

The `Provider` annotation makes the class discoverable by the JAX-RS framework.
The `Produces` annotation links the writer to the intended output of your method.

For Jersey, adding the JacksonFeature should do the trick (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e8449)

```
final Application application = new ResourceConfig()
    .packages("org.glassfish.jersey.examples.jackson")
    .register(MyObjectMapperProvider.class)  // No need to register this provider if no special configuration is required.
    .register(JacksonFeature.class);
```