# How to declare an element that can contain another element or just text

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Newbie question. I did search before asking! I would like to model some Java classes such that the JAXB marshalled output is as follows (essentially HTML table data - XML):

```
   <td>
      <span class="myClass">assets</span>
   </td>
   <td>some text</td>
   <td>some more text</td>
```

Basically, it is trivially easy to get things working with  all taking text values. But when I try to include provision for the above span (declared to be a separate XMLElement) then I cannot get the "text" on its own. For instance, it either wraps the text in the name of the String attribute I declare to hold the text, or if I try to switch that off by using @XmlValue then it complains you cannot mix XMLElement and XMLValue in the same declaration (even though I am using only one or the other depending on context as above - each td contains either a span OR text but not both at the same time).

The sort of output is:

```
<td><span class="myClass">assets</span></td><td><value>some text></value></td>
```

And ultimately the question boils down to "how do i remove those "value" elements?"
I would like:

```
<td><span class="myClass">assets</span></td><td>some text</td>
```

I can post data but really only if absolutely necessary. What I was hoping is the above explanation  would be sufficient for someone to kindly provide a solution.

Thank you all for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so here goes with the answer. Looks simple enough but hope it saves others an hour of hacking and scouring jaxb documentation. Do the following - the real issue here is getting the TD to be polymorphic of sorts - in my situation I only wanted EITHER a span OR plain text value. Didn't have a usecase for both.

```
@XmlSeeAlso(Span.class)
@XmlRootElement(name = "td")
public class TableData {

private List<Object> items;

public TableData() {}

public TableData(List<Object> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

@XmlMixed
@XmlAnyElement
public List<Object> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Object> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

}
```

I have a Span class (also declared separately as an XMLElement. The trick is to relax the restriction on what type a value can be (don't try to declare two attribute types, one string for the text, and one Span.class for span situations). Also note the @XmlSeeAlso, @XmlMixed, and @XmlAnyElement. There are situations where @XmlElementRef, and @XmlElementRefs would suit better. In my situation here, going with the @XmlAnyElement worked without fuss.

For a more complete discussion, I'd recommend answer given by Blaise Doughan in this post: [JAXB - Java/ XMLValue & XMLElement conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495156/jaxb-java-xmlvalue-xmlelement-conflict)